# How to fill area under path

Tags: adobe-illustrator, inkscape, fill

first off i couldn't suck more at graphic design. That's why i usually ask for some help - but since i need those graphics for different websites i usually end up with more trouble than before when implementing them.

This time i have a SVG, it's a path (i think?) with some dots. Everything is transparent, besides the path, the dots, and a circle around the dots for seperating path and dots (it looks like it is not a drawn through line with the seperation circle). I want to **fill the area below the path** (red lines) with a specific color. How ***** is this possible?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a path that looks like this:
[image: original path]

You can fill the area below it by defining the area you'd like to fill.
I would suggest using the pen tool, click on one of the end points to continue the path. (Notice the slash icon that appears below the pen cursor.)
[image: continue path]

You can hold shift to constrain the lines you're adding to right angles, and click to draw the corners of a rectangular area below the path where you want the fill.

And click on the other end to close your original path (the icon below the pen cursor turns to a circle to indicate you're closing the path.)
[image: adding rectangular area]

Then you'll have a closed path that you can fill:
[image: closed path]

[image: add fill]

[image: done]

Comment: Additionally, if you don't want the contour to show up all around, do this with a duplicate of the graph line, and remove the stroke after adding a fill.

Answer (score 4):

Inkscape: If it's a path you can use it to divide a rectangle to two parts. The function is Division in the Path menu. Use a copy because the path vanishes.

[image]

No guarantee because I cannot be sure if your curve is a path. It can be a group which contains many different parts. Division needs a single path and the rectangle or a closed path below to be functional.

In Illustrator learning what the Shape Builder can do would be your best bet. The functions of the Pathfinder Panel and Object > Path > Divide Objects Below are as useful. Get the User's Guide!

As I said before your image can be something else than a path. If it happens to be a bitmap image, only embedded in a much promising but nothing giving SVG wrap you should either draw the equivalent path manually or try Inkscape's Paint Bucket (=the Fill Bounded Areas -tool). It works with the bitmap you see on your screen. That's far from exact, but still very useful, when screen resolution is enough.